# How could I clone apache-superset from github and run it in my local system

Tags: github, flask, github-for-windows, apache-superset

I need to run the GitHub project in my system and I didn't find any solution for that, so I need help from anybody

Comment: All of that is documented [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup-local-environment-for-development) in their GitHub repo

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using the docker instance. In this [blog post](https://preset.io/blog/2020-05-11-getting-started-installing-superset/) you can find details

Comment: I don't have that much specifications to use docker in my system, is any other solution. I clone the project from github, because I need multi tenency support in Apache superset

Comment: I am not too familiar with the installation process, sorry. I use Preset that is a hosted version and docker for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Install superset as per documentation instead of cloning.
Then follow the documentation below to enable multi-tenancy support.
https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/3729